# Cómo puedo poner una etiqueta dentro de otra etiqueta sin que la segunda sea detectada como etiqueta?

Tags: html

Quiero poner `<alo alo>` dentro de una etiqueta `<p>` pero esta es detectada como etiqueta y no me permite ponerla como texto

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Esto es exactamente lo que quiero poner:

```
<p><alo alo></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tambien puedes usar las etiquetas `<pre></pre>` y `<code></code>` si lo que quieres es mostrar el texto como codigo, de igual forma utilizas `&lt;` y `&gt;` para remplazar < y >.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <code>
            &lt;p&gt;alo alo &lt;p&gt;
        </code>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

si tu intencion es mostrarlo como codigo hay una libreria [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Para poder imprimir < y > simplemente necesitas reemplazar `<` por `&lt;` y `>` por `&gt;`.

Ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p> &lt;alo alo&gt;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

> Si comienzas con `&lt;` el siguiente símbolo > se mostrará igual, pero es un buena practica finalizarlo con `&gt;`